# Find string according to words count

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get below result in **SQL Server** with **single query**?!

example data [**description_column**]:

- LG television
- BOSCH vacuum cleaner 55 mm
- SONY home theater 55 watt

String to search:
**LG 55 vacuum theater home**

**UPDATE:**
I wanna order result according to words count in search term, so desired result is as below:

1. SONY home theater 55 watt (contains three words: **55**,**theater**, **home**)
2. BOSCH vacuum cleaner 55 mm (contains two words: **55**,**vacuum**)
3. LG television (contains one word: **LG**)

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Is it possible to get below result in SQL Server with **single query**?!"* Yes, it is. You'll want to look into full text indexes, and table variables (or string splitters, but I recommend the former). Good luck!

Comment: Look up `contains` and full text searches.

Comment: I've searched about contains, near, full text indexes and relative topics but couldn't find any example for my purpose ;(
if it's possible for you, please send me an example link.

Comment: Which version of SQL?

Comment: @Sparky Sql Server v.14

Comment: So, just to confirm, @FarshadKazemi, SQL Server 2017?

Comment: @Larnu, Yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Use String_Split or something similar to create a table for each word. 
   LG 55 Vacuum theater home

```
  #table_of_words (text varchar(32))
  text
  LG
  55
  Vacuum
  Theater
  Home
```

B) join the created table with the
   main table using an expression like

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description 
FROM main_table  Main
JOIN #table_of_words  WD ON Main.Description Like '%'+WD.text+'%'
```

If you want to only include whole words, you will need to put spaces into the ON clause:  (Thanks ZLK)

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description 
FROM main_table  Main
JOIN #table_of_words  WD ON ' '+Main.Description+' ' 
LIKE '% '+WD.text+' %'
```

Also note that if you want to deal with commas, you'll need some additional tweaking.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description 
FROM main_table  Main
JOIN #table_of_words  WD ON ' '+Main.Description+' ' 
LIKE '%[, ]'+WD.text+'[, ]%'
```

Here is how to order the result by number of words found

```
SELECT description,count(*) as NumberWords
FROM main_table  Main
    JOIN #table_of_words WD ON ' '+Main.description+' ' 
    LIKE '% '+WD.text+' %'
GROUP  BY  description
ORDER BY NumberWords DESC
```

Comment: This'll work, but I'd be careful about the performance here. `LIKE` clauses with leading wildcards aren't SARGable; meaning the engine will need to check the value of every row with a full table scan.

Comment: And it also leaves you open to matches like '1234567890555555551234567890' being like '%55%' or 'algae' matching '%LG%' without directly matching the text (which I would assume was not desired).

Comment: Are you *sure* this doesn't work @FarshadKazemi [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd47262984079aa8583ad3175c385f80)

Comment: Farshid, update the question with your code, can't really tell what isn't working

Comment: @Larnu, As I mentioned in question, result must order by according to words count.
So, first result must be: SONY home theater 55 watt , because it contains three words of search term: 55, theater, home

Comment: @FarshadKazemi no where do you mention that is the required logic. *Maybe* the expected result infers it, but it's a stretch. Details like that should be in the question.

Comment: I agree, that wasn't at all clear in the question.    However, it can easily be solved.  If you update your question to show your actual query, I'll show you how to order it like you want.

Comment: I modified my answer to show how to order by number of matching words

Comment: Thanks dear @Sparky. That is what I want 