# How can order query result based on word occurrence count

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a product table and wanna search on **Tag** column that results must sort by count of occurrence of words.

```
ID | Tag                            
---------------------------------------    
1  | LG television                      
2  | BOSCH vacuum cleaner 55 mm         
3  | SONY home theater 55 watt      
---------------------------------------
```

String to search: **LG 55 vacuum theater home**

Desired results:

```
1. SONY home theater 55 watt (contains three words: 55,theater,home)
2. BOSCH vacuum cleaner 55 mm (contains two words: 55,vacuum)
3. LG television (contains one word: LG)
```

There is a solution in [Find string according to words count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856346/find-string-according-to-words-count) that uses **LIKE** and is very **slow**.

I want to implement it by **FULLTEXT** search

**UPDATE**: I tried below solution but results are wrong

```
SELECT ft.[Rank], p.Tag
FROM tblProducts AS p
       INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(tblProducts, Tag, 'LG 55 vacuum theater home') AS ft
                  ON ft.[Key] = p.ProductID
ORDER BY ft.[Rank] DESC;
```

Comment: Can't you just use a `JOIN`?

Comment: _"I want to implement it by FULLTEXT search"_ -> [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @gvee, question is updated; please check it

Comment: @Sami, What's your mean ?